# How to make the insets on either side of this cyllinder symmetrical

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects, edit-mode

[image][image]From there, I'll be adding asymmetrical elements, like the cavity you can see on the one side, and a protruding element on the other. I want to stick multiple cyllinders together and have them fit end to end using that cavity-protrusion method (like an electrical socket). This, I assume, means I can't just use a modifier. 

Tl;dr I just want the insets to be symmetrical

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, have you tried using the mirror modifier along Z with "bisect" checked ?
Could you add a little diagram of the expected end result ?

Comment: Apologies the original question was vague, I added a diagram to better explain. I want symmetrical insets on both flat ends of a cylinder, with a couple faces on one end extending outwards, and a couple faces on the other, moved inwards. That way, if you stack multiple length-wise, they would slide into each other. In order for that to happen though, I need to start with symmetrical insets

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could build the symmetrical elements first using the *Mirror Modifier* first.

[image]

Then apply the modifier, and work on the asymmetrical elements.

[image]

**Edit**

Ok, based on that additional info, here's how you could go about doing so:

Create the first cylinder with the cuts. Then duplicate it, and flip the second one so that the insets are facing each other. Then, just grab the extruded faces, and move them in/out of the cylinder face by the same distance that you did for the first one. You can type in distances after activating the grab tool for exact distances.

[image]

Comment: Or use the mirror editing options in edit mode...

Comment: I really appreciate you going through the process of building it to explain. I don't think I posed my question properly, but I meant on either side of the cylinder. I put a diagram in my original question to show what I mean. I want symmetrical insets, but on one side, I want certain faces to protrude, and on the other, certain faces to move inwards. That way, if you stack multiple length-wise, the protruding shaft of one cylinder would fit into the concave part of the next cylinder.

Comment: Alright, updated the answer